# Django Deployed on apache returns: The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, apache

I have a problem when I deployed django on Apache. I have a view :

```
@csrf_exempt
def login(request,id=-1):
        if request.method == 'POST':
                if 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' in request.META:
                    auth_header = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']
                    encoded_credentials = auth_header.split(' ')[1]
                    decoded_credentials = base64.b64decode(encoded_credentials).decode("utf-8")\
                        .split(':')
                    username = decoded_credentials[0]
                    password = decoded_credentials[1]
                    if username is '' or password is '':
                            return JsonResponse({'Please enter username & password': 1})
                    info = Personel.validation(username,password)
                    if info == -1:
                            return JsonResponse({' page_not_found': 404})
                    if info == 0:
                            return JsonResponse({' permission_denied': 403})
                    if info == 1:
                            personpass = Personel.objects.filter(username=username,password=password)
                            dd=Personel.serializer.__get__(personpass[0])
                            data2 = json.dumps(list(personpass[0].serializer))
                            data2 = json.dumps(dd)
                            return JsonResponse(data2,status=200, safe=False)
```

I call it using this url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/views/login
```

on my development host (127.0.0.1:8000) when I call it and provide a user/password by http authorization it works fine.

Yesterday I deployed my site on server. it is windows and I am using Apache, When I call the above route it returns this error

```
The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead
```

Nothing is changed. My server is deployed fine and `django admin` page works fine. I can not find the reason why this happens

Answer (score 0):

Well,
The problem was because apache does not pass http authorization to django. so I had to add these lines

```
    # this can go in either server config, virtual host, directory or .htaccess 
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

into http conf